# Strange Empty Arrays with Negative Step Slicing in NumPy (v1.23.5)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-slicing

I'm encountering a puzzling issue with negative-step slicing in NumPy (version 1.23.5). While basic slicing and positive-step slicing work as expected, specific combinations with negative steps are producing empty arrays unexpectedly.

Key Observations:

Empty Arrays: Slicing operations like x[2:9:-1] and x[3:8:-1] on a 1D NumPy integer array return empty arrays instead of the expected reversed sub-sequences.

Partial Functionality: Reverse slicing the entire array with x[::-1] does produce the correct reversed sequence, suggesting negative-step functionality is not entirely broken.

Environment Agnostic: The issue persists across different environments (Colab and IDLE), implying it's not environment-specific.
Array Integrity: The original array remains unmodified after the slicing operations, ruling out unintended modifications as the cause.

Variations: Other negative-step slicing combinations with similar ranges, like x[1:8:-1] and x[3:8:-1], also result in empty arrays.
System Information:

NumPy version: 1.23.5
Python version: 3.10.12
Operating system: Windows

Here is a code snippet,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYydt.jpg)